# Browser Inspector how to know if image or other resources belongs to which css or js file that was failed to load?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, google-chrome-devtools, firefox-developer-tools

I can see some images in my webpage that are not loading the reason is the wrong path inside the css or js file but how to know which js or css file is trying to load that resource. I tried too much in browser's inspector to find some way but I cannot figure out so I have to search each js and css file for the resource name.   Is there any way to know the exact js or css file that is trying to load the failed resource. 
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The Firefox and the Chrome DevTools provide a way to see what initiated the request of a resource within their *Network* panels.

**Chrome DevTools**

The *Network* panel within Chrome's DevTools provides information about the origin of a request within an [*Initiator* column](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/reference#requests). All entries except the ones saying 'Other' link to the line within the JavaScript, CSS, or document, which caused the request.
For JavaScript calls it shows the stack trace that led to the request on hover.

[image: *Initiator* column in Network panel of Chrome DevTools]

It even allows you to [highlight the initiators and dependencies](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/reference#initiators-dependencies) by holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd> and hovering entries within the list.

**Firefox DevTools**

The Firefox DevTools Network Monitor has a [*Cause* column](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor#Cause_column) indicating if a request came from JavaScript, the document, CSS, or some other source.

For JavaScript calls it provides the stack trace within a *Stack Trace* side bar when selecting the entry.

[image: *Cause* column in Network Monitor of Firefox DevTools]

Unfortunately, for causes other than JavaScript it doesn't provide much useful information or links to the source files yet (as of Firefox 55). Therefore I've [filed several enhancement requests](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1230922) to improve this feature.