# Image is rendering sometime in body property

Tags: html, css

I am using a page with HTML body and some property associated with body defined in the head section. while Executing the page image is rendering sometime and sometime not.

```
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      background-image: url('Assets/Img/bg2.jpg');
      background-size: cover; /* <------ */
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: center center; /* optional, center the image */
    }
  </style>
</head>
```

body section

```
<body class="signup-page">
    <div id="content"></div>
</body>
```

What is the issue Exactly? Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you try looking at the network tab in your developer tools? The only issue I could see happening was if the image failed to load.

Comment: @Phillip what You mean by network tab

Comment: Open your developer tools. On Firefox, I press cmd+alt+i. There should be a tab called network. I know Chrome has this as well.

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+I in Chrome and F12 in IE

Comment: @Phillip yes image failed to load ..how to resolve this

Comment: This might be simply connection problem, try to open the image url in separated window and see if it loads always. Also what is the error code and message you're seeing ? [See this for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45879825/browser-inspector-how-to-know-if-image-or-other-resources-belongs-to-which-css-o)

Comment: @Anddo i inspect the same way as you sent the link but sometime url is like http://localhost:784849/Home/Assets/Img/bg2.jpg and some time http://localhost:784849/Assets/Img/bg2.jpg when it render second url issue is resolved but why is it happening not known

Comment: So there is /Home added !!. Try use the tag `<base href = " localhost:784849" />` and see if it continues